# Nav bar doesn't render on the show page - Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I currently have an index of subscribers. Right now the user has the option to click on each subscriber to get additional information about that subscriber. The show page displays with the right content except that I don't see the navbar? Everything is in the application layout page so I can't figure out why this is? Here is some code.

APPLICATION/LAYOUT:

```
<body>

  <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
      <ul>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <%= yield %>

</body>
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Find Out What This Guest Likes</h1>

  <p>This is <%= @subscriber.first_name%> <%= @subscriber.last_name %></p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure what else to show. Let me know if I'm missing something. Thank You!

Comment: does `_navigation.html.erb` exists in layouts folder?

Comment: as @Marv-C said, check if the partial `layouts/_navigation.html.erb` exists.
If so, can you please post your controller code?